# Edit draggable points using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've seen examples online about the how to make draggable points in highcharts, but I can't seem to find an example of how to have the draggable feature as a way to edit where the point is located, and how to use a textbox (tooltip) as a way to edit the data for the point as well. I've been reading up in the documentation and can't seem to find a way. The only way I can think to make this happen is using the custom html table code in the tooltip function, but I can't seem to get it to work. What I'm really wanting at the end of the day is to allow the user two methods of editing data points: either by dragging the point, or entering in the data into a field manually (preferably the tooltip when they hover over the data point). Does anyone have any suggestions or know if this is even possible? I've tried many searches online and in Stack Overflow and have not had any success finding someone who's been able to do this yet...Your help is appreciated in advance as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple with Highcharts. You just need to find the right point and update its data value. For example:

```
const yInput = document.getElementById('yVal');

document.getElementById('applyInputValue').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const selectedPoint = chart.series[0].points.find(p => p.selected);

  if (selectedPoint) {
    selectedPoint.update({
      y: +yInput.value
    });
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ygL7t23u/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: I really like what you've put here and I really appreciate it. I'm wondering though, is there a way to do this through the tooltip box that pops up, or does it have to be a form submit button below the chart? That's the part that I'm really stuck with. With your help now, I at least have a decent option for manually editing a point by typing in the value. Hopefully there's a way to edit the point within the tooltip box that pops up? Let me know if you have any ideas here on that.

Comment: Hi @ADT, Yes, it's possible. You need to use `formatter` function for tooltip and add some tags and attributes for the allowed ones. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7bdupw6o/ Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#filtering

Comment: I hesitate to ask you this since you've been so helpful already, but how do I go about modifying how the tooltip shows instead of using the "defaultFormatter" to something more custom without this code breaking? I want to make the tooltip more to my liking, but any time I try to get rid of the defaultformatter part in the "const defaultVal" definition, the tooltip breaks. I like what's being done with the "defaultVal.push" part that gets added on, but the data showing up above it is not how I want it. I am struggling here to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ADT, You can just remove the default formatter part and return a plain string from the function. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qvw8e15f/

Comment: I like what you've put in here, and that helps me better understand this. Unfortunately, the "Apply" button on the tooltip doesn't seem to be working in updating the value whichever point in the series I'm attempting to update.  What I found fixes this is by adding in "hoveredPoint = this.point;" on line 34 right after the line with "let value = this.series.name + ': ' + this.point.y;". I think it got omitted accidently when I asked for your previous help on getting rid of the defaultFormatter. Thanks so much for all your help on this! You're awesome!